# How to get encoded data sent in form of bytes using body and convert to JSON?

Tags: java, json, web-services, arrays

I am recieving the following byte array format using UTF-8 :

Printing description of requestData:
<7b227573 65724944 223a2238 35303130 33353222 2c22686f 73706974 616c4163 636f756e 74223a22 30303031 30313634 3235222c 2273616c 65734f72 67616e69 73617469 6f6e223a 22415531 30222c22 6e65774c 6f636174 696f6e22 3a7b226e 65774c6f 63617469 6f6e4465 7461696c 73223a5b 7b226c6f 63617469 6f6e5374 72656574 31223a22 20222c22 6c6f6361 74696f6e 4e616d65 223a2261 6263222c 226f7264 65725265 76696577 6572456d 61696c22 3a22222c 22696d73 4d616e61 6765724e 6f746522 3a22222c 226c6f63 6174696f 6e506f73 74436f64 65223a22 222c2269 6d734d61 6e616765 724e616d 65223a22 222c226f 72646572 41707072 6f766572 4e616d65 223a2222 2c226f72 64657252 65766965 7765724e 6f746522 3a22222c 226c6f63 6174696f 6e4f7264 65724379 636c6544 61797322 3a223233 222c226c 6f636174 696f6e43 6f756e74 65724e6f 7465223a 22222c22 6c6f6361 74696f6e 43697479 223a2222 2c226f72 64657241 7070726f 7665724e 6f746522 3a22222c 226f7264 65724170 70726f76 6572456d 61696c22 3a22222c 226c6f63 6174696f 6e526567 696f6e22 3a22222c 22696d73 4d616e61 67657250 686f6e65 223a2222 2c226c6f 63617469 6f6e4163 636f756e 74223a22 4e657722 2c22696d 734d616e 61676572 456d6169 6c223a22 222c226f 72646572 52657669 65776572 50686f6e 65223a22 222c226f 72646572 52657669 65776572 4e616d65 223a2222 2c226f72 64657241 7070726f 76657250 686f6e65 223a2222 7d5d7d7d>

This is a JSON.And with the help of web services i want to convert the data to JSON and then the object of class.

How can i proceed please help.

Answer (score 0):

Steps would be to

```
1. First convert the byte[] to String also to specify charset of UTF-8

Charset utf8charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
String json = new String(bytes, utf8charset)

2. Use JSON Parser to convert the string to JSON object.
```